# How to create a loop to replace NaN value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I want to replace `NaN` with last value by each alphabet(`A`, `B`, `C`) separately, then merge them.
I tried this code for each alphabet(ABC),but not sure how to loop all alphabet:

```
df_A = df[df['ST'] == A].fillna(method = 'ffill')

df_B = df[df['ST'] == B].fillna(method = 'ffill')

merge(df_A,df_B)
```

Comment: how about `df.groupby('ST').ffill()`?

Comment: For your reference, A, B, and C are called _letters_ (or _characters_), not _alphabet_. Also, please do not post screenshots of data and code, but post the actual data and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a copy of `df` that is filled with the values from the first column, and then combine the new dataframe and the original one to fill in the holes:

```
copy_df = pd.DataFrame(df['ST'], columns=df.columns).ffill(axis=1)
df.combine_first(copy_df)
#  ST CO NO
#0  A  2  4
#1  A  3  A
#2  A  A  3
#3  B  8  6
#4  B  7  B
#5  B  5  8
#6  B  B  B
#7  C  9  4
#8  C  C  1
```